# Adding a db for replication into mysql

Tags: mysql, replication

Currently I have these settings. I am adding a new db called mydb3. How to enable the replication for this new db? Currently I have copied the table schema into both master and slave. What other changes must I do ? Can I just add binlog_do_db=mydb3 and replicate-do-db=mydb3 on both master and slave?

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

innodb_file_per_table
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
innodb_buffer_pool=5G
innodb_log_file_size=512M


server-id=1
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-error=mysql-bin.err
binlog_do_db=mydb1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

For the slave here is the settings.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0


innodb_file_per_table
server-id=1339951115
master-host = ***
master-user = ***
master-password =***
master-port = 3306
replicate-do-db=mydb1
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer** to what I think you are asking... Yes, you can have multiple `binlog_do_db` statements.

**Long answer...**

The binlog and replicate commands can be a bit confusing.  Roughly this is what happens:

- If the Master has one or more `binlog_do_...` statements, they limit what is written to the binlog.  See Bug below.
- If the Master has one or more `binlog_ignore_...` statements, they list what is *not* written to the binlog; everything else is.
- If you have a mixture of the two, I don't know what happens.

For Replication, the binlog is copied to the Slave.  (The binlog *could* be just sitting there for a form of backup -- No slave involved.  In particular, a Slave can have its own binlog.)

On a Slave, `replicate_do_...` allows only those things in; `replicate_ignore_` tosses the listed things.  A mixture is a mystery.

What you listed (`binlog_do_db=mydb3` and `replicate-do-db=mydb3`) is redundant in that the `replicate_do` does nothing that the `binlog_do` didn't already do.  (Namely replicate only `mydb3`.)  It is more efficient to filter on the Master than on the Slave.  (There are multiple use cases where this is not practical.)  That is, *you* should have several `binlog_do` on the master, and nothing on the Slave.

A server that is not being used as a Slave has no use for `replicate_*`.  (So *you* should not add it to the *Master*.)

I am trying to phrase everything carefully because of various topologies that you might not be interested in.  For example...

A "dual-Master" topology has two Masters replicating from each other.  That is, each is both the Master to the other, and the Slave to the other.  I that case each is both a Master and a Slave.  But I digress.

**Bug**

If the `USE` command in effect matches any of the `binlog_do*`, the command will be written.  Note:  `USE x; INSERT INTO y.z ...` depends on `x`, not `y`!  This "bug" (aka 'feature') has tripped up many a DBA.

**Side note:**

For security, do not include the `master-password` in my.cnf; do it only when you execute `CHANGE MASTER` to establish the Master-Slave connection.  (Future versions may disallow it anyway.)